# How do I generate a unique ID for a DIV under JSF 1.2?

Tags: html, dom, jsf, richfaces

I need a unique id for some DIVs under JSF 1.2, how do I go about doing this in a manner that can be resolved later for use in a Javascript function?

Traditionally I use either JSF HTML or Richfaces components, which automatically use JSF to generate an unique id and then use [rich:clientId()](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/12/richfaces-built-in-client-functions/) to resolve that id. I just haven't found a component that will just give me a DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BalusC is partially correct about `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` producing a div, thought strangely enough you need to include a style or styleClass element to guarantee that it produces a div. Here is the quote from the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/index.html).

> If the "style" or "styleClass" attributes are present, and the "layout" attribute is present with a value of "block", render a "div" element

When you put an ID on the h:panelGroup then it will be prepending with a JSF id. This doesn't work on JSF Facelets however, where you will run into duplicate ID issues.

Answer (score 3):

The [`<h:panelGroup layout="block">`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/panelGroup.html) will render a `<div>`.

When the `layout` attribute is omitted and when it has another attributes which should end up in HTML, like `styleClass` and so on, it will by default render a `<span>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can render a div as discussed in this question, 
[What jsf component can render a div tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951593/what-jsf-component-can-render-a-div-tag)