# Is there an "abstract" component in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

Like div/span in HTML, I'd like to know if there has similar tags in JSF. It should be meaningless in HTML display, but only for organizing document composition.

For example:

```
<h:abstractGroup id="a" rendered="false">
    ...
</h:abstractGroup>
```

Comment: Possibile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951593/what-jsf-component-can-render-a-div-tag

Comment: define "organizing document composition"?

Comment: @meriton: I mean to construct the logical structure of a document, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendering of a group of child components can be controlled with the facelet tag  `<ui:fragment>`.

See also [Alternative to ui:fragment in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf)

Comment: Oddly, `ui:fragment`, `h:panelGroup` did not work for me. I'm using PrimeFaces (3.0-M3), at last I've found `p:outputPanel` which worked for me, though. I'm curious what's the difference between `ui:fragment` and `p:outputPanel`? Do you know?

Answer (score 1):

h:panelGroup does exactly this, and it renders as div or span too, automatically detecting which is required.