# Place p inside span or force h:outputText to generate div around text

Tags: html, jsf

In my project, I take raw text from user and send it to server to do the following

- decide what type of each word is
- add a `span` around it with a related CSS class
- keep the original text structure (i.e `\r\n` means paragraph-end so i can wrap it in a `p`)
- display the result back to the user

using

```
<h:outputText value="#{wordTypeBean.wordTypeValues}" escape="false" />
```

In short, I am doing all the html markup at server-side. The `return`ed result is something like this (of course as a long String, the result indented for readability):

```html
<span> <!-- from h:outputText -->
  <p> <!-- the returned String coming from the Bean starts here -->
    <span class="interjection">Hello</span>
    <span class="noun">World</span>
    !
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="noun">Life</span>
    <span class="verb">is</span>
    <span class="adjective">beautiful</span>
    .
  </p> <!-- the returned String coming from the Bean ends here -->
</span> <!-- from h:outputText -->
```

But `h:outputText` generates `span` element around the text. Even though I have seen no problems, so far. But, I have a feeling that it is not right as I read that in html it is illegal to place `p` inside `span`.

Is there any way to force `h:outputText` to generate `div` around the text coming from Bean or is there a legal/better way to accomplish this?

Here is a snip from Chrome's DevTool's element tab:
[image: Chrome DevTools screenshot]

Comment: I cannot remove id, since i have a <code>h:inputHidden</code> to capture any edits made on the displayed text and send it (as is) back to my Bean via <code>p:commandButton</code> using <code>onmousedown="$('#topF\\:tabview\\:wordsToSubmit').val($('#topF\\:tabview\\:wordTypeEditor').html());"</code>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This,

```
<h:outputText value="#{wordTypeBean.wordTypeValues}" escape="false" />
```

doesn't generate any additional HTML. So you actually don't have exactly that tag.

Based on your HTML DOM inspector screenshot, you appear to actually have this:

```
<h:outputText id="wordTypeEditor" value="#{wordTypeBean.wordTypeValues}" escape="false" />
```

Indeed, this will generate a `<span>` element because you've explicitly specified an attribute which must end up in client side, the `id` attribute.

Get rid of that `id` attribute, move it into a `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` wrapping the `<h:outputText>`.

```
<h:panelGroup id="wordTypeEditor" layout="block">
    <h:outputText value="#{wordTypeBean.wordTypeValues}" escape="false" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

If you don't need to reference it elsewhere in ajax, just a `<div id="wordTypeEditor">` is also fine.

```
<div id="wordTypeEditor">
    <h:outputText value="#{wordTypeBean.wordTypeValues}" escape="false" />
</div>
```

#### See also:

- [What jsf component can render a div tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951593/what-jsf-component-can-render-a-div-tag)

Comment: It worked for me after moving every attribute from h:outputText to h:panelGroup except escape="false"... Learning new things everyday. Exactly what i have been looking for. Thank you.