# How do I get the id of a jsf component parent knowing its id?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I have a `<h:commandLink id="link1" ..>` within a `<div id="div1">`. I want to get the id of this div( the parent element of `<h:commandLink id="link1" ..>` in the backing bean, I don't want to get it directly but I want get it going through its child(  ).

Please How could I achieve this.
Here you can find a sample of my code.

```
<div style="text-align:center;    height: 50px; width: 100%; background: wheat; 
                border: 1px #6e5d40 solid; margin-top: 5px;">
        <h:form>
            <ui:repeat var="label1" value="#{backingBean.listOfSearchValue}">
                <span class="filterLabel">#{label1} <h:commandLink class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></h:commandLink>
                </span>
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't just use a plain HTML `div`, but use a `h:panelGroup layout="block"`. Then it is just a matter of getting the parent of the `UIComponent` (the button in your case).

See also [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) [`Components`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components) for help with finding components from within your bean, especially [`getClosestParent(UIComponent component, Class<C> parentType)`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/3.1/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Components.java#L386).

Comment: Was writing this as a comment too with one addition: Using the 11 upvoted answer in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951593/what-jsf-component-can-render-a-div-tag is a solution to with plain html (using passtrough attributes). I just could not find if it would be a namingcontainer then... But I would not rely on the id of a parent in a bean for 'businesslogic' (although it is hopefully in the controller and not in the real service, but still)... Coupling becomes to tight then