# Show / Hide another element based on primefaces p:fileUpload

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I tried to show a label which value is file name of the file uploaded by user...

Here is my simple form

```
<h:form>            
        <p:outputLabel value="#{indexBacking.fileName}" rendered="#{indexBacking.showLabel}" id="fileNameLabel"/>                                      
        <p:fileUpload id="uploadImage" mode="advanced"
                      dragDropSupport="false" required="true"
                      sizeLimit="5120000"
                      requiredMessage="Harap upload KTP anda"
                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpeg|png|pdf)$/"                                                  
                      fileUploadListener="#{indexBacking.handleUpload}"
                      update="fileNameLabel"                               
                      auto="true"/>
</h:form>
```

Here is my backing

```
public void handleUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    showLabel = true;
    System.out.println("file uploaded");
    UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
    fileName = file.getFileName();
}
```

But every time I upload the file, the label did not show...Can anyone explain to me why? Thanks

Comment: is showLabel set to false before called by handeUpload? if so, as Microbob said, you can't update unrendered component. try to wrap the outputLabel with panel or panelGrid, then update the panel or panelGrid instead of the outputLabel itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update="fileNameLabel"` should address the h:form since it is the wrapper of your label which has to be rendered.

**Edit 14.12.2018**

try something like this:

```
<h:form> 
   <div jsf:id="uploadImageWrapper">           
        <p:outputLabel value="#{indexBacking.fileName}" rendered="#{indexBacking.showLabel}" id="fileNameLabel" for="uploadImage" />                                      
        <p:fileUpload id="uploadImage" mode="advanced"
                      dragDropSupport="false" required="true"
                      sizeLimit="5120000"
                      requiredMessage="Harap upload KTP anda"
                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpeg|png|pdf)$/"                                                  
                      fileUploadListener="#{indexBacking.handleUpload}"
                      update="uploadImageWrapper"                               
                      auto="true"/>
   </div>
</h:form>
```

Notice that i also added the for-attribute in the label, it's not necessary but cleaner.

Comment: but i don't want to update the form, because in my current project if i update form, there will be another request to database...Btw this can only accomplish by update the form?

Comment: you could wrap your label and fileUpload in a new element. Like Blablabla said, this could be a panel or a simple div with a jsf:id.

Comment: the 'jsf:id' being explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951593/what-jsf-component-can-render-a-div-tag